# Локализация в WPF

Tags: локализация, wpf, ресурсы, c#

В моем проекте встал вопрос о локализации. Заранее не известно на сколько языков он будет переведен. Сейчас у меня выбор между двумя способами:

1. Ресурсы приложения (таблица строк)
2. baml-файлы

Какой из этих способов вы посоветуете? Прошу подкрепить Ваш выбор пояснениями (почему, да как). Если вы знаете другие способы, жду.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, если проект готов, почему бы не попробовать один из способов и в зависимости от ситуации сменить стиль локализации. Локализация - завершающий этап, думаю зависит от размера проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Если еще не слишком поздно, попробуйте easybaml.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете локализацию (l10n) и интернационализацию (i18n). Это не одно и то же.

Если речь всё-таки о интернационализации, то на мой взгляд лучше текстовые ресурсы. С ними работать проще: они просты как пробка и понятны всем. Их легко редактировать и доставлять. Легко поддерживать.

Вообще, ваше приложения должно изначально разрабатываться так, чтобы интернационализация выполнялась по ходу, иначе всегда будет шанс потерять что-то, если заниматься ею после того, как проект готов.

Answer (score 0):

некоторое время назад у меня стояла такая же задача. Про свои изыскания я написал [здесь](http://dev-sol.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf.html) и [здесь](http://dev-sol.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf_14.html).